# Compare row wise elements of a single column. If there are 2 continuous L then select lowest from High column and ignore other. Conversly if 2 L

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

```
    High    D_HIGH  D_HIGH_H
33  46.57   0   0L
0   69.93   42  42H
1   86.44   68  68H
34  56.58   83  83L
35  67.12   125 125L
2   117.91  158 158H
36  94.51   186 186L
3   120.45  245 245H
4   123.28  254 254H
37  83.20   286 286L
```

In column D_HIGH_H there is L & H at end.
If there are two continuous H then the one having highest value in High column has to be selected and other has to be ignored(deleted).
If there are two continuous L then the one having lowest value in High column has to be selected and other has to be ignored(deleted).
If the sequence is H,L,H,L then no changes to be made.

Output I want is as follows:

```
    High    D_HIGH  D_HIGH_H
33  46.57   0   0L
1   86.44   68  68H
34  56.58   83  83L

2   117.91  158 158H
36  94.51   186 186L

4   123.28  254 254H
37  83.20   286 286L
```

I tried various options using list map but did not work out.Also tried with groupby but no logical conclusion.

Comment: how many dimension? i can help you with excel.  I am also interested in this in Panda.

Comment: Did you notice consecutive L or H have consecutive index. The H to keep is always the second and the L to keep is always the first. So you can probably filter out before this when your dataframe is not yet sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
g = ((l := df['D_HIGH_H'].str[-1]) != l.shift()).cumsum()

def f(x):
    if (x['D_HIGH_H'].str[-1] == 'H').any():
        return x.nlargest(1, 'D_HIGH')
    return x.nsmallest(1, 'D_HIGH')

df.groupby(g, as_index=False).apply(f)
```

Output:

```
        High  D_HIGH D_HIGH_H
0 33   46.57       0       0L
1 1    86.44      68      68H
2 34   56.58      83      83L
3 2   117.91     158     158H
4 36   94.51     186     186L
5 4   123.28     254     254H
6 37   83.20     286     286L
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the letter, then compute a custom group and [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with a function that depends on the letter:

```
# extract letter
s = df['D_HIGH_H'].str.extract('(\D)$', expand=False)

# group by successive letters
# get the idxmin/idxmax depending on the type of letter
keep = (df['High']
           .groupby([s, s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()], sort=False)
           .apply(lambda x: x.idxmin() if x.name[0] == 'L' else x.idxmax())
           .tolist()
        )

out = df.loc[keep]
```

Output:

```
      High  D_HIGH D_HIGH_H
33   46.57       0       0L
1    86.44      68      68H
34   56.58      83      83L
2   117.91     158     158H
36   94.51     186     186L
4   123.28     254     254H
37   83.20     286     286L
```

Comment: A good solution.

Comment: @Tornike except I had made a mistake :p but thanks to you I read it again and noticed it!

Comment: In the end, the main thing is to work ;)